# when I click submit, it goes straight onto another page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

My form submits to another page when I do not want it to. The current page is known as create_session.php

I want the form to submit if all of the validation and the postback is met and even after that the user needs to click "Ok" when the confirmation box appears. Except this never happens. When the user clicks on the submit button, it takes the user straight to another page "QandATable.php", it doesn't care about about validation(), the postback() and the confirmation box doesn't appear.

So what I want to know is that when the user clicks on the submit button, how can I get it so that it checks for the validation(), postback() and confirmation box (showConfirm()) before even going onto the next page.

I believe the problem is the submit button and the form action. Below is the form:

```
    <form action="QandATable.php" method="post" id="sessionForm">

<p><input type="text" id="txtMarks" name="textMarks" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="5" /><br/><span id="marksAlert"></span></p>
<p><strong>Room:</strong> <input type="text" id="room" name="roomChosen" value="<?php echo $roomChosen; ?>" />
                <br/><span id="roomAlert"></span></p>      <!-- Enter Room here--> 

<p><input class="questionBtn" type="submit" value="Prepare Questions" name="prequestion" onClick="myClickHandler()"/></p> 
</form>
```

Below is the javascript click handler where it checks for the validation(), postback() and then if both of those met then it will showConfirm().

```
function myClickHandler(){ 
     if(validation()){ 
        postback(function(message) { 
            if (message == "") 
                showConfirm(); 
        }); 
     } 
}
```

Comment: Do you see any Javascript error in your browser console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the default action isn't applied when the submit button is clicked. In this case, the default action is to submit the form.

Try adding a `return false;` such as

```
<input class="questionBtn" type="submit" value="Prepare Questions" name="prequestion" onClick="myClickHandler(); return false;"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return `false` from your `onClick` handler to prevent the form from being submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Two changes; you need to pass the function, not the function's return value, and you need to return `false`:

```
<input class="questionBtn" type="submit" value="Prepare Questions" name="prequestion" onClick="myClickHandler" />
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^ here
```

and

```
function myClickHandler(){ 
     if(validation()) { 
        postback(function(message) { 
            if (message == "") 
                showConfirm(); 
        });
     }

     return false;
}
```